# Jenkins Github-plugin failing to create webhooks

Tags: jenkins, github

I have created a personal access token at https://github.com/settings/tokens. I have given this personal access token all permissions that I could give.

```
3e......................d7
```

Which I have configured in the Jenkins credentials, username is my Github username and password is my personal access token (3e...d7)

I've configured the Jenkins job to use these credentials and reran the job. Unfortunately the Jenkins admin page says this:

There were some problems while registering or removing one or more GitHub webhooks. Would you like to view the problems?

```
github.com:username/drupal-build
There are no credentials with admin access to manage hooks on GitHubRepositoryName[host=github.com,username=username,repository=drupal-build]
```

How do I debug this issue?